# Django DetailView + urls with custom parameters

Tags: python, django

Simplified version of forum app in Django. What I want to do is have an url in the form of `forum/forum_slug/thread_slug/`. I have no idea how to define and pass the custom `forum_slug` to urlpatterns.

```
# models.py
class Forum(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=60)

    # ...

    def threads(self):
        _threads = Thread.objects.filter(forum=self)
        return _threads


class Thread(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    forum = models.ForeignKey(Forum)

    # ...

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return '/%s/%s' % (self.forum.slug, self.slug)


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField('Title', max_length=60)
    thread = models.ForeignKey(Thread)

    # ...



# ******************************************************
# views.py
# ******************************************************
class ForumDetail(MetadataMixin, DetailView):
    model = Forum
    context_object_name = 'forum'
    template_name = 'forum/forum.html'

    name='forum'

    # meta...


class ThreadDetail(MetadataMixin, DetailView):
    model = Thread
    context_object_name = 'thread'
    template_name = 'forum/thread.html'
    name = 'thread'

    # meta...



# ******************************************************
# urls.py
# ******************************************************
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 
        'forum.views.index',
        name='index'
        ),

    url(r'^(?P<slug>[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$', 
        ForumDetail.as_view()),

    # here it comes
    url(r'^(?P<forum_slug>[a-zA-Z0-9-]+/?P<slug>[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$', 
        ThreadDetail.as_view()),
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want URL pattern for slugs. Below is the example you can try.

```
# URL example: /forum/this-is-a-forum-1/this-is-a-thread-1/
url(r'^forum/(?P<forum_slug>[\w-]+)/(?P<thread_slug>[\w-]+)$', ThreadDetail.as_view()),
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Like I said, I did not -- and still do not -- know how to define `forum_slug` to pass to urlpattern. Above I came out with some solution but that is not "the one" I wish to have. Wish it worked without `reverse`.

Answer (score 0):

@rayy: Thanks. No, this is not what I was looking for -- I simply do not know how to define `forum_slug` in it. That's what I was asking for. :-) Well, I figured out kinda more verbose solution but, frankly, I do not like it:

```
# models.py
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

class Thread(models.Model):
    #... like before
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('thread_url', (), {'forum_slug': self.forum.slug, 'slug': self.slug})

# urls.py
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # ...
    url(r'^(?P<forum_slug>[\w-]+)/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', ThreadDetail.as_view(), name='thread_url'),)

# index.html / forum.html (in a loop)
<a href="{% url 'forum: thread_url' forum_slug=forum.slug slug=thread.slug %}">{{thread.title}}</a>
```